# Form.is_valid() всегда возвращает false, почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Форма рендерится правильно, в request.POST приходят правильные значения, а при проверке form.is_valid() всегда возвращает false. Соответственно form.save() никогда не отрабатывает. Помогите найти причину.

forms.py

```
class NewPushMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
user_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=MobileDevice.objects.filter(status=1, token__isnull=False),
    label='Номера телефонов',
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
        'class': 'select2_multiple form-control',
        'style': 'height:300px'
    })
)

class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    widgets = {
        'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'style': 'width:100%'
        })
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.fields['title'].label = 'Заголовок'
    self.fields['content'].label = 'Сообщение'


def save(self):
    list_user_id = self.cleaned_data.get('user_id')
    title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
    content = self.cleaned_data.get('content')

    for user_id in list_user_id:            
        new_msg = Message.objects.create(
            user_id=user_id,
            pre_title=content[:255],
            title=title,
            content=content
        )
```

views.py

```
class PushMessageCreate(View):
def get(self, request):
    return render(request, 'mobile_api/push_create_form.html', context={            
        'form': NewPushMessageForm()
    })

def post(self, request):
    form = NewPushMessageForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():            
        form.save()
        return redirect('push_list')

    return render(request, 'mobile_api/push_create_form.html', context={
        'form': form
    })
```

Форма выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не пробовали в шаблоне вывести ошибки формы?

Comment: Пробовал, пусто. Ошибок нету.

Comment: `fields = ['title', 'content']` - то есть у вас на странице отображаются только эти 2 поля? Если да, то как вы заполняете `user_id` перед отправкой формы? Я не вижу, что оно у вас помечено как необязательное поле.

Comment: user_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=MobileDevice.objects.filter(status=1, token__isnull=False))  заполняю результатом запроса

Comment: Форма рендерится так как нужно

Comment: Похоже что при добавлении телефона вы добавляете строку с телефоном (или что у вас там), а  форма ждет id объекта либо сам объект.

Comment: Те вам нужно по тексту записи найти в базе объекты, которые им соответствуют, либо может в качестве pk использовать тоже поле, которые вы отображаете. Немного сумбурно, но лень разбираться какие у вас там поля, думаю суть понятна.

Comment: Если достаю значения из request.POST[''] и вручную сохраняю во views, то все отрабатывает. Не могу понять что не так срабатывает при вызове метода is_valid() всегда возвращает false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переписать вот так:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Form.is_valid() == False будет даже если нет ошибок, но Form.is_bound=False

Form.is_bound == True будет тогда, когда форма форма заполнена.
Переписав **init** вы забыли передать данные в **init** родителя.